# Get params from URL using $stateParams, UI-router. Undefined Value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I am passing a value from one state to another using UI-Router. In my controller when the url is updated I am trying to get access to the second parameter of my url using `$stateParams`, but for some reason I can get access to the first parameter but the second one is *UNDEFINED*. This is my code:

state 1, URL:

```
 http://localhost:16009/#/5nqeAPqlv21/
```

state 2, URL:

```
 http://localhost:16009/#/5nqeAPqlv21/details/PP163Ku3dOR
```

candidateContoller.js:

```
//go to state 2 (same controller for parent and child views)
$state.go('index.details', { "submissionIdd": publicSubmissionId });

//when located in the new state and new url:
console.log($stateParams.submissionIdd); //shows undefined 
console.log($stateParams.token);  //shows 5nqeAPqlv21
```

App.js:

```
$stateProvider       
    .state('index',
        {
            url: '/:token/',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'AngularJS/Templates/indexView.html',
                    controller: 'candidateController as candCtrl'
                },
                'sectioncandidate@index': {
                    templateUrl: (_isNotMobile) 
                      ? 'AngularJS/Templates/candidatesView.html' 
                      : 'AngularJS/Templates/candidatesMobileView.html'
                }
            }

        })          

     .state('index.details', {
         url: 'details/{submissionIdd}',
         views: {
             'sectioncandidate@index': {
                 templateUrl: (_isNotMobile) 
                   ? 'AngularJS/Templates/candidateView.html' 
                   : 'AngularJS/Templates/candidateMobileView.html'
             }
         }
     })
```

Comment: Does this works  `'details/:submissionIdd',`

Comment: I tried that option, but dont know why i can still get the first param but not the second one.

Answer (score 2):

You do experience standard behavior of the UI-Router and **Parent/Child** state defintion:

- parent state declares $stateParams (as `url: '/:token/'`) - so there is just one declared - a **`token`**
- child state gets all from parent(s), plus declares new parameter (as **`url: 'details/{submissionIdd}'`**) - so it has both defined - **`token`** and **`submissionIdd`**,

So, while child has access to both params, parent state has just a *token* parameter

state 1 === PARENT, URL:

```
http://localhost:16009/#/5nqeAPqlv21/
```

here we will have `submissionIdd` undefined

state 2 === CHILD, URL:

```
http://localhost:16009/#/5nqeAPqlv21/details/PP163Ku3dOR
```

both are there `submissionIdd=PP163Ku3dOR` and `token=5nqeAPqlv21`

Extend - [there is a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rJMPRbD5S1YYvSkJrhq4?p=preview)

This states definition (in the plunker a bit adjusted)

```
.state('index',
    {
        url: '/:token/',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'indexView.html',
                controller: 'candidateController as candCtrl'
            },
            'sectioncandidate@index': {
                templateUrl: 'parent.html'
            }
        }

    })          

 .state('index.details', {
     url: 'details/{submissionIdd}',
     views: {
         'sectioncandidate@index': {
             templateUrl:'child.html',
         }
    })
```

will properly show state params for these links

```
href
<a href="#/5nqeAPqlv21/">
<a href="#/5nqeAPqlv21/details/PP163Ku3dOR">
<a href="#/5nqeAPqlv21/details/other">
ui-sref
<a ui-sref="index({token: '5nqeAPqlv21'})">
<a ui-sref="index.details({token: '5nqeAPqlv21', submissionIdd: 'another'})">
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rJMPRbD5S1YYvSkJrhq4?p=preview)

Comment: Since we can say **`$stateParams`** are local to **`state`** where as **`$state.params`** are global. They have dictionary of all the parameters, correct me if I'm wrong, Thanks :)

Comment: why if i execute directly in the browser (typing the whole url) http://localhost:16009/#/5nqeAPqlv21/details/PP163Ku3dOR ; my controller only print token (the first param). dont understand.

Comment: There is a link to plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/rJMPRbD5S1YYvSkJrhq4?p=preview it should show all that in action, hope it helps

Comment: @PankajParkar we can access all params as you say, but would that be a way to go? I mean - to access *(rather try to access)* child state parameters in parent state controller? My suggestion would be - declare parameters where they are used. Even if they must be moved up *(to parent)*. Maybe my answer was not clear enough - but that was what I tried to say...

Comment: @RadimKöhler No! It wouldn't be good way to access child data in parent. Your answer was very clear(upto the point') +1, may be what I wrote is confusing. I'm not let OP to use `$state.params` instead, I just clearing understanding of `$stateParams` vs `$state.params`. You must have seen most of the people confused between these two options. I was just concluding. Thanks :)

Comment: I am trying base on what u said. I can see $state.params has: token: "5nqeAPqlv21" and submissionid: "PP163Ku3dOR"  but $stateParams only has token. dont know why it happens?

Comment: I would put it this way: As @PankajParkar has stated - **`$state.params`** gives access to all params.. even to child ones. BUT ... it is not easy to react to them. Because parent is initiated.. and is not changing - when child states are changed, there is no information that $state.params.xyz is having different value. We would need to introduce the watch `$scope.$watch("$state.params", function(params) {...})` and have to have assigned the `$scope.$state = $state` in parent... but that is a bit odd solution. If we have params on proper state.. any change will trigger its re-creation...

Comment: There is an adjusted plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/NgS4q9XCfbxt1xO5oDRe?p=preview (open the console and observe changes when navigating among children). It simply shows, that we can have access to all params, even in parent.. but it makes code really very complex, hard to read and very hard to maintain ... I'd say

Comment: yes. Thanks. I think i got what u mean. what is still unknown for me is why $stateParams does not have both params when browsing directly to the child state. Well, in my case it does not have both params even when I go to the child state from the parent state.any thoughts?

Comment: It is this way. UI-Router starts with a parent state. It detects its **defined** params.. tries to read them from URL and then creates an instance of `$stateParams` *(where only token is)*. Then, I mean after that, once this is done - UI-Router is starting to solve child state. It takes parent `$stateParams` and extends them.. and calls child controller *(if any, otherwise implicit)*. So, because first is dispatched parent ... and then a child... that's why **parent never gets child `params as $statePrams`**. On the other hand, $state.params is a reference to the latest $stateParams evaluated

Comment: Thanks again, i understood that "parent never gets child params as $statePrams" but if I open a browser and i paste  http://localhost:16009/#/5nqeAPqlv21/details/PP163Ku3dOR. Im not in the parent state. It is the child state, and even it is the child state   $stateParams is not able to retrieve the second param that is in the url. i mean i have an error in my code? or i still don't understand the theory? I will try to put an example of my code online.

Comment: The point is ... you access that in parent controller. So, regardless of the fact, that child is (will be after parent) also created... at the moment when parents controller is triggered.. just its params are passed by UI-Router. Sorry I cannot help as you need ;(

Answer (score 0):

> You can prefer not to pass the the params in the URL unless there is an explicit requirement. I would prefer to use $stateParams in controller to fetch the data.
>   For this you need to define the default params in the state to
>   make it work.

```
 $stateProvider .state('index.details', {
         url: 'details',
          params: {
              submissionIdd: 'default',
          },
         views: {
             'sectioncandidate@index': {
                 templateUrl: (_isNotMobile) ? 'AngularJS/Templates/candidateView.html' : 'AngularJS/Templates/candidateMobileView.html' ,
             controller: function($stateParams){
                      console.log($stateParams.submissionIdd)
                   }
             }
         }
     })
```

Comment: what if I dont go tho second state from a previous state, if not i type the full url   http://localhost:16009/#/5nqeAPqlv21/details/PP163Ku3dOR. Actualy i need to get that param if the user refresh the page, so i am able to fetch the data. Anyway i still can not see the second param using  your option. do not know what is wrong